# Ideas for Altoid cans?

Tags: reuse

My wife is 'addicted' to Altoids. We have hundreds of empty cans and have already recycled thousands. I was thinking I could put them to good use at home. Looking for ideas.

[image]
<sup>'altoid tins' by 'secret agent josephine' on Flickr</sup>

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! There are a few reuse tips on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altoids#Altoids_tins)

Answer (score 3):

The Internet is full of Altoids tins ideas -- they are very popular for creating little pocket survival kits and much more. [22 Ways to Reuse an Altoids Tin](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2011/01/30/22-manly-ways-to-reuse-an-altoids-tin/) and [227 Best Geeky Altoids Tin Projects on Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/charlesbuchwald/geeky-altoids-tin-projects/) are the first two hits on a simple Google search.

Answer (score 2):

I just turned my empty altoid can into a pill box where I keep my aleves and Tylenol pills etc

Comment: I said I have hundreds of cans and I don't take hundreds of different kinds of medications. What would I do with hundreds of altoid cans full of pills. That's an idea for one altoid can, not hundreds.

Answer (score 2):

If she is addicted to them, there are recipes online for DIY Altoids. They could be kept in the tins you have. That would also prevent you from accumulating more tins.

As others have said, there are a lot of projects online utilizing the tins. Either you could make the projects, or find a vendor on Etsy or the like that would be interested in lot quantities of Altoid tins.

Answer (score 0):

Repainted altoids tins make great cigarette box...I know, hit me

Comment: Great, so I should start smoking so that I can fill those. Great idea.